# Mongoose create method has no respond

Tags: node.js, mongoose

There's no respone for below save method. I wonder why.

```
app.post('/something', function (req, res) {

    mainModel.save(req.body.data ,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(data)
        }

    });

});
```

Here's how my models/main.js look like http://pastebin.com/eQSFXWb5

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return any response after save. you should return response ie. `return res.status(400).send()`.

you can try it

```
app.post('/something', function (req, res) {
    if(!req.body.data) {
       return res.status(400).send({masg: 'Invalid data'});
    }
    var newMainModel = new mainModel(req.body.data);

    newMainModel.save(function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(400).send({masg: 'Error occurred'});
        }
        console.log(data);
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: why return? I don't get it.

Comment: I didn't use `else` so if error occurred then next step no need to execute

Comment: Is your `req.body.data` perfect according to model ? can you check by `console.log()` ?

Comment: yes. but if it's not i should show at least the error msg.

Comment: you can check `req.body.data` before create `newMainModel `. updated my answer

Comment: I got it work, because my connection to mongodb failed. but the data can't be inserted, coz the schema is wrong, I susepct.